# Extending Django User Model: ForeignKey Error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to extend the Django user model to include another field. As described within the documentation, I've extended the field as follows:

```
   class Employee(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    manager_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='employees')
```

I would like manager_id to be self referential and relate to a user (rather than defining a new manager table) and simply display the new field within the general User page. For this purpose, as instructed within the docs, I've also added the following:

```
class EmployeeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Employee
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'employee'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (EmployeeInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

However, I receive the following exception:

```
<class 'dhtmlScheduler.models.Employee'> has more than 1 ForeignKey to <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
```

Could anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: I think you required `manager_id = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='employees')` if you want `manager_id` to be self referential??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want `manager_id` to be self referential then Aamir's comment on your question is the way to go.

If you want `manager_id` to be a reference to the `User` model the way it is in your example code, you need to tell the `EmployeeInline` which foreign key to use.

Like this:

```
class EmployeeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Employee
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'employee'
    fk_name = 'manager_id'
```

This will show a user's employees on his/her admin page. The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-a-model-with-two-or-more-foreign-keys-to-the-same-parent-model) have a few more details.